# Center the text in the circle

Tags: android, line, center, draw, geometry

I have to draw a circle with a number in each piece of my circle.
    My problem is i can't center the text where i want.
    Why the center to draw the text is not the same than the center to draw the line ???

sfdzqgs
 fsdgf dsbfd  ds   ds fdg sfgnfhggdf  wdvfbdfsf dsgfhdr sdgfdshstqrssgqg sqfgshdf dgerfztiaruhis rguhtrqiorgeuqzengoh bçzioqrgethriZQGEHOQRAGIRGOGfjfn fgkjkjvfrejn eofnbfoig vjlj vvjfndbjfdnj  figsn

```
/*enter code here
 * Author : 
 * date : 06/12/2013
 * 
 * 
 * enter code here
 */

package com.example.ando_dessin_test;

//merci a http://supertos.free.fr/supertos.php?page=1066

import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Align;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Desactiver la barre de titre de notre application
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    // Passer la fenêtre en full-creen == cacher la barre de notification
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(new RenderView(this));
    }

    // Création d'une classe interne RenderView pour gérer un affichage simple
    // permettant
    // de montrer que nous occupons bien tout l'écran
    class RenderView extends View {

    public RenderView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    }

    // Dessinons sur la totalité de l'écran
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawRGB(0, 0, 0);

    // Instance de Paint pour définir l'attribut couleur de notre point,
    // ainsi que
    // sa taille.
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    // Nous allons dessiner nos points par rapport à la résolution de
    // l'écran
    int iWidth = canvas.getWidth(); // Largeur
    int iHeight = canvas.getHeight(); // Hauteur
    // float radius = 0;//Radius caused an error so I initialized this
    // variable

    Random rand = new Random();
    // j'ai l'impression detre dans les etoiles avec ces petits points
    // Affichons 10000 points de toutes les couleurs
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    // Affecter une couleur de manière aléatoire
    paint.setARGB(255, rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256),
    rand.nextInt(256));
    // Puis dessiner nos points dans le canevas
    canvas.drawPoint(rand.nextInt(iWidth), rand.nextInt(iHeight),
    paint);
    }

    // aficchons notre fameux cercle
    // Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    Paint circlePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    circlePaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    circlePaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    circlePaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    float rayonDuCercle = canvas.getWidth() / 2;
    canvas.drawCircle((float) canvas.getWidth() / 2,
    (float) canvas.getHeight() / 2, rayonDuCercle, circlePaint);
    float rayonDuCerclePetit = canvas.getWidth() / 6;
    canvas.drawCircle((float) canvas.getWidth() / 2,
    (float) canvas.getHeight() / 2, rayonDuCerclePetit,
    circlePaint);

    /*
    * // Random rand = new Random(); //Affichons 100 segments de toutes
    * les couleurs for (int i=0; i < 100; i++) { // Affecter une
    * couleur de manière aléatoire paint.setARGB(255,
    * rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256)); //
    * Définir l'épaisseur du segment paint.setStrokeWidth
    * (rand.nextInt(10)); // Puis dessiner nos points dans le cavenas
    * canvas.drawLine(rand.nextInt(iWidth), rand.nextInt(iHeight),
    * rand.nextInt(iWidth), rand.nextInt(iHeight), paint); }
    */
    paint.setARGB(255, rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256),
    rand.nextInt(256));
    // Définir l'épaisseur du segment
    paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
    // Puis dessiner nos points dans le cavenas
    // okcanvas.drawLine((float)((float)Math.cos(0)*rayonDuCerclePetit)+canvas.getWidth()/2,
    // canvas.getHeight()/2,canvas.getWidth()/2+rayonDuCercle,
    // canvas.getHeight()/2, paint);
    // okcanvas.drawLine((float)((float)Math.cos(Math.PI/2)*rayonDuCerclePetit)+canvas.getWidth()/2,
    // ((float)Math.sin(Math.PI/2)*rayonDuCerclePetit)+canvas.getHeight()/2,canvas.getWidth()/2+rayonDuCercle*(float)Math.cos(Math.PI/2),
    // rayonDuCercle*(float)Math.sin(Math.PI/2)+canvas.getHeight()/2,
    // paint);
    // okkk
    // canvas.drawLine((float)((float)Math.cos(Math.PI/4)*rayonDuCerclePetit)+canvas.getWidth()/2,
    // ((float)Math.sin(Math.PI/4)*rayonDuCerclePetit)+canvas.getHeight()/2,canvas.getWidth()/2+rayonDuCercle*(float)Math.cos(Math.PI/4),
    // rayonDuCercle*(float)Math.sin(Math.PI/4)+canvas.getHeight()/2,
    // paint);

    // initPaint(paint,);

    // pourquoi j'utilise 2 boucles ? Parce que pour limiter l'espace
    // memoire j'utilise le même canva et la seul difference entre ces
    // deux element est la couleur.
    // cette boucle affiche des rayons
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

    setRayon(canvas, (Math.PI / 4) * i, paint, rayonDuCercle,
    rayonDuCerclePetit);
    }

    paint.setTextAlign(Align.RIGHT);

    // cette boucle affichage du texte
    for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
    setText(canvas, paint, String.valueOf(i), (Math.PI / 4) * i,
    rayonDuCercle * 0.7, 80);
    // si je suis le dernier element j'affiche le 9 du centre
    if (i == 8) {
    paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
    setText(canvas, paint, String.valueOf(i + 1), (Math.PI / 4)
    * i, rayonDuCercle * 0, 80);
    }
    }

    }

    /*
    * info pour unen raison que j'ai pas chercher a comprendre l'angle
    * positif s'affiche comme si c'été un ange negatif . Donc je bidouille
    * en multipliant l'angle par -1
    */
    void setRayon(Canvas canvas, double angleRad, Paint paint,
    float rayonDuCercle, float rayonDuCerclePetit) {
    // angleRad=angleRad*-1;
    angleRad = (Math.toRadians((double) 70) + angleRad) * -1;
    canvas.drawLine(
    (float) ((float) Math.cos(angleRad) * rayonDuCerclePetit)
    + canvas.getWidth() / 2,
    ((float) Math.sin(angleRad) * rayonDuCerclePetit)
    + canvas.getHeight() / 2,
    canvas.getWidth() / 2 + rayonDuCercle
    * (float) Math.cos(angleRad),
    rayonDuCercle * (float) Math.sin(angleRad)
    + canvas.getHeight() / 2, paint);
    }

    /*
    * info pour unen raison que j'ai pas chercher a comprendre l'angle
    * positif s'affiche comme si c'été un ange negatif . Donc je bidouille
    * en multipliant l'angle par -1
    */
    void setText(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, String Txt, double angleRad,
    double rayonTxt, int sizeText) {
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setTextSize(sizeText);
    angleRad = (Math.toRadians((double) 50) + angleRad) * -1;

    // axe des ordonees enhaut a gauche -> canvas.drawText(Txt, (float)
    // Math.cos(angleRad)*(float) rayonTxt,
    // (float)Math.sin(angleRad)*(float) rayonTxt, paint);
    // ligne suivante j'ai centree l'axe
    canvas.drawText(Txt, (float) Math.cos(angleRad) * (float) rayonTxt
    + canvas.getWidth() / 2, (float) Math.sin(angleRad)
    * (float) rayonTxt + canvas.getHeight() / 2, paint);

    }

    /*
    * private void initPaint(Paint paint, Drawable drawable, float
    * textHeight, float baselineOffset) { paint = new Paint();
    * paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE); paint.setColor(Color.BLUE); paint
    * = new Paint(); paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    * paint.setAntiAlias(true); paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    * paint.setTextSize(30); paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER); FontMetrics
    * fontMetrics = paint.getFontMetrics(); baselineOffset =
    * fontMetrics.bottom; // bottom is the maximum amount that the text
    * descends // I'm not sure why this is different from descent...
    * textHeight = fontMetrics.bottom - fontMetrics.top; // drawable =
    * getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher); }
    */

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Klaus66 and Ramesh for your answer. The goal of this circle is to launch something if you poke a number in the circle. For example if i poke the number 1 the piece with the number 1 will change of color and i will call a function. Then : The goal to draw everythings is to manage the the color and it 's more easy to use.

Comment: I see. I just saw your png and I understood that I understood nothing of your problem. Let me suggest you to **draw your rays before the circles**, so that the circles then cover the abundancy. then... It's a matter of **math** (aaaargh)! you'll have to measure each of your numbers and then move them to the appropiate coordinates. The center one is the easiest, of course. for the rest you will use **trigonometric** functions (I guess just sin and cos are enough) to determine the exact coordinates. Try to imagine your numbers as rectangles. I think you, like me, draw a lot your ideas on paper.

Comment: All the numbers, except the central one seem to be much too lefty, you should add a horizontal offset. And all, including the central seem to be much too high, so you should add a vertical offset, too. And (sorry to point out a lot of things) the outer circle seems too big for the canvas (or the canvas is too big for the screen). This is because the radius should take in account the stroke size. See, the stroke is **not inside** the circumference, is **on** it (I once faced the same issue)

Comment: Bonjour, Thank you for your help , it's working but...
The goal of this software is for a game.
The number in the circle was only for fun .
Now the challenge is to make a circle in each part and to insert a image and insert or delete a letter "+" Then I must draw the circle and 3 "+" arround the circle. Each "+" is like a life for the game. Thus I must create a function do draw these circles and a function to insert 3 "+" and a function to delete a "+" You can see what i want to say in the image .
I am working to do it. Merci. ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cYwYy.jpg)

Answer (score 7):

I'm having a lot of fun with answering this question, here's my last effort:

[image]
[image]

The first image is just for testing and determinig the empyrical values of the extra padding; the second one is the final product after removing the extra code.

The illusion of circularity is **nearly perfect** (enough for human eye, I guess)

Here is the modified layout, **activity_main.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="#f000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/bg"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt9"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="9"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt1"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/txt9"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/txt9"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="12dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt8"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/txt1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txt1"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="12dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="8"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt2"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/txt9"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/txt9"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="2"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt3"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/txt2"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/txt9"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="12dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="3"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt4"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/txt9"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/txt9"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="4"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt5"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/txt4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txt4"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="5"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt7"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/txt9"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txt9"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="7"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt6"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/txt7"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txt9"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="12dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="6"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the updated code (you'll get even more optimizations), **MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.numbers;

import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity
extends Activity
{

    final Paint pnt = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    final Random rnd = new Random();

    RelativeLayout rlBG;

    @Override
    protected final void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Make it fullscreen
        // Desactiver la barre de titre de notre application
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        // Passer la fenêtre en full-creen == cacher la barre de notification
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rlBG = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.bg);
        rlBG.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        final CustomView cv = new CustomView(this);
        rlBG.addView(cv);
        sendViewToBack(cv);
    }

    private static void sendViewToBack(final View v)
    {
        final ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)v.getParent();
        if (parent != null)
        {
            parent.removeView(v);
            parent.addView(v, 0);
        }
    }

    private class CustomView extends View
    {
        public CustomView(final Context ctx)
        {
            super(ctx);
        }

        @Override
        protected final void onDraw(final Canvas cnv)
        {
            //
            super.onDraw(cnv);

            // Clear the canvas
            cnv.drawRGB(0, 0, 0);

            // Instance de Paint pour définir l'attribut couleur de notre point,
            // ainsi que sa taille.

            // Nous allons dessiner nos points par rapport à la résolution de
            // l'écran
            final int width = cnv.getWidth(); // Largeur
            final int height = cnv.getHeight(); // Hauteur
            final float rayonDuCercle = (float) (cnv.getWidth() *.5) - 5;
            final float rayonDuCerclePetit = (float) (cnv.getWidth() * .167);

            //
            drawStars(cnv, width, height);

            //
            drawRays(cnv, rayonDuCercle, rayonDuCerclePetit);

            //
            drawCircles(cnv, width, height, rayonDuCercle, rayonDuCerclePetit);
        }

        private final void drawCircles
        (
            final Canvas cnv, final int width, final int height,
            final float rayonDuCercle, final float rayonDuCerclePetit
            )
        {
            //
            // aficchons notre fameux cercle

            pnt.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ffff0000"));
            pnt.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
            pnt.setStrokeWidth(10);
            cnv.drawCircle((float) (cnv.getWidth() * .5),
                (float) (cnv.getHeight() * .5), rayonDuCercle, pnt);
            cnv.drawCircle((float) (cnv.getWidth() * .5),
                (float) (cnv.getHeight() * .5), rayonDuCerclePetit, pnt);

            // ????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
            /*
            Random rand = new Random(); //Affichons 100 segments de toutes
            les couleurs for (int i=0; i < 100; i++) { // Affecter une
            couleur de manière aléatoire paint.setARGB(255,
            rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256)); //
            Définir l'épaisseur du segment paint.setStrokeWidth
            (rand.nextInt(10)); // Puis dessiner nos points dans le cavenas
            canvas.drawLine(rand.nextInt(iWidth), rand.nextInt(iHeight),
            rand.nextInt(iWidth), rand.nextInt(iHeight), paint); }
             */

            pnt.setARGB(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256),
                rnd.nextInt(256));
            // Définir l'épaisseur du segment
            pnt.setStrokeWidth(2);

            // ????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????

            // Puis dessiner nos points dans le cavenas
            // okcanvas.drawLine((float)((float)Math.cos(0)*rayonDuCerclePetit)+canvas.getWidth()/2,
            // canvas.getHeight()/2,canvas.getWidth()/2+rayonDuCercle,
            // canvas.getHeight()/2, paint);
            // okcanvas.drawLine((float)((float)Math.cos(Math.PI/2)*rayonDuCerclePetit)+canvas.getWidth()/2,
            // ((float)Math.sin(Math.PI/2)*rayonDuCerclePetit)+canvas.getHeight()/2,canvas.getWidth()/2+rayonDuCercle*(float)Math.cos(Math.PI/2),
            // rayonDuCercle*(float)Math.sin(Math.PI/2)+canvas.getHeight()/2,
            // paint);
            // okkk
            // canvas.drawLine((float)((float)Math.cos(Math.PI/4)*rayonDuCerclePetit)+canvas.getWidth()/2,
            // ((float)Math.sin(Math.PI/4)*rayonDuCerclePetit)+canvas.getHeight()/2,canvas.getWidth()/2+rayonDuCercle*(float)Math.cos(Math.PI/4),
            // rayonDuCercle*(float)Math.sin(Math.PI/4)+canvas.getHeight()/2,
            // paint);

            // initPaint(paint,);
        }

        private final void drawRays
        (
            final Canvas cnv, final float rayonDuCercle,
            final float rayonDuCerclePetit
            )
        {
            // pourquoi j'utilise 2 boucles ? Parce que pour limiter l'espace
            // memoire j'utilise le même canva et la seul difference entre ces
            // deux element est la couleur.
            // cette boucle affiche des rayons
            for (int i = 8; i > -1; --i)
            {
                setRayon(cnv, (Math.PI * .25) * i, pnt, rayonDuCercle,
                    rayonDuCerclePetit);
            }
        }

        private final void drawStars
        (final Canvas cnv, final int width, final int height)
        {
            // j'ai l'impression detre dans les etoiles avec ces petits points
            // Affichons (1/100th of screen size) points de toutes les couleurs
            final int stars = (int) ((width * height) *.01);
            for (int i = stars; i > 0; --i)
            {
                // Affecter une couleur de manière aléatoire
                pnt.setARGB(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256),
                    rnd.nextInt(256));
                // Puis dessiner nos points dans le canevas
                cnv.drawPoint(rnd.nextInt(width), rnd.nextInt(height), pnt);
            }
        }

        /*
         * info pour unen raison que j'ai pas chercher a comprendre l'angle
         * positif s'affiche comme si c'été un ange negatif . Donc je bidouille
         * en multipliant l'angle par -1
         */
        void setRayon
        (
            final Canvas cnv, double angleRad, final Paint pnt,
            final float rayonDuCercle, final float rayonDuCerclePetit
            )
        {
            angleRad = (Math.toRadians(90) + angleRad) * -1;
            cnv.drawLine
            (
                ((float) Math.cos(angleRad) * rayonDuCerclePetit) +
                (float) (cnv.getWidth() * .5),
                ((float) Math.sin(angleRad) * rayonDuCerclePetit) +
                (float) (cnv.getHeight() * .5),
                (float) (cnv.getWidth() * .5) + (rayonDuCercle *
                    (float) Math.cos(angleRad)),
                    (rayonDuCercle * (float) Math.sin(angleRad)) +
                    (float) (cnv.getHeight() * .5), pnt
                );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Better on, you could use an xml drawable, as I do in an app of mine:

Just put this circle.xml in your res/drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval"
    >
    <solid android:color="@color/disc_flat" />
    <stroke
        android:color="@color/disc_flat_lt_semi"
        android:width="2dp"
    />
</shape>
```

solid is the color that fills the circle, while stroke is the circumference (optional), with given a "pencil" width.
Now, set a text with (say) width=height="20dp" and give it this circle as background.
Don't forget to set gravity="center"... et voilà! les jeux sont fait.
It's very lightweight, resolution independent, and doesn't consume cpu time.
I defined my colors in res/values/colors.xml (only because I want them to be reusable), but you can use your colors in the usual formats: #argb, #rgb, #aarrggbb, #rrggbb - as you prefer.
A picture of my circles in action.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here I'm trying to cheat...

[image]

It's just 9 textboxes (the central one is twice the others).
To make it a bit more realistic, 2 and 7 should have a bit of paddingBottom, 3 and 6 a bit of paddingTop, 1 and 4 a bit of paddingRight and finally 8 and 5 a bit of paddingLeft added.
"a bit" to be determined empyrically (I'd try 4, 8, 10, 12, 16, 20 dp)

With the stars, no titlebar + fullscreen and the circle + rays... **maybe** you're done
Of course, this is cheating; just an **ALTERNATIVE** solution.
Of course the angle is always 45°, but starting at 90°, and going (counterclockwise): 135°, 180°, 225°, 270°, 315°, 360°.
I think it would take you 5 minutes (or less) to make a copy of your project and try this layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="#f000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt9"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="9"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt1"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/txt9"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/txt9"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt8"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/txt1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txt1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="8"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt2"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/txt9"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/txt9"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="2"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt3"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/txt2"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/txt9"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="3"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt4"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/txt9"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/txt9"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="4"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt5"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/txt4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txt4"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="5"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt7"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/txt9"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txt9"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="7"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt6"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/txt7"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txt9"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="6"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Just remove the text drawing part and change the start angle to 90°. See if it can be a valid alternative

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE:

Look at this... not much different from your goal (yes, cheating):

[image]

The **rays are under** the circles and the **outer circle fits** the canvas (I subtracted half of the stroke size).
I used my layout (see my other answer) and changed your code to:

```
package com.example.numbers;

import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity
extends Activity
{

    final Paint pnt = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    final Random rnd = new Random();

    RelativeLayout rlBG;

    @Override
    protected final void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Make it fullscreen
        // Desactiver la barre de titre de notre application
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        // Passer la fenêtre en full-creen == cacher la barre de notification
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rlBG = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.bg);
        rlBG.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        final CustomView cv = new CustomView(this);
        rlBG.addView(cv);
        sendViewToBack(cv);
    }

    private static void sendViewToBack(final View v)
    {
        final ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)v.getParent();
        if (parent != null)
        {
            parent.removeView(v);
            parent.addView(v, 0);
        }
    }


    private class CustomView extends View
    {
        public CustomView(final Context ctx)
        {
            super(ctx);
        }

        @Override
        protected final void onDraw(final Canvas cnv)
        {
            //
            super.onDraw(cnv);

            // Clear the canvas
            cnv.drawRGB(0, 0, 0);

            // Instance de Paint pour définir l'attribut couleur de notre point,
            // ainsi que sa taille.

            // Nous allons dessiner nos points par rapport à la résolution de
            // l'écran
            final int width = cnv.getWidth(); // Largeur
            final int height = cnv.getHeight(); // Hauteur
            final float rayonDuCercle = (float) (cnv.getWidth() *.5) - 5;
            final float rayonDuCerclePetit = (float) (cnv.getWidth() * .167);

            // Draw the stars in the background
            drawStars(cnv, width, height);

            // Draw the rays before
            drawRays(cnv, rayonDuCercle, rayonDuCerclePetit);

            // Draw the circles after
            drawCircles(cnv, width, height, rayonDuCercle, rayonDuCerclePetit);
        }

        private final void drawCircles
        (
            final Canvas cnv, final int width, final int height,
            final float rayonDuCercle, final float rayonDuCerclePetit
            )
        {
            // aficchons notre fameux cercle
            // Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
            final Paint pntCircle = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

            pntCircle.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ffff0000"));
            pntCircle.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
            pntCircle.setStrokeWidth(10);
            cnv.drawCircle((float) (cnv.getWidth() * .5),
                (float) (cnv.getHeight() * .5), rayonDuCercle, pntCircle);
            cnv.drawCircle((float) (cnv.getWidth() * .5),
                (float) (cnv.getHeight() * .5), rayonDuCerclePetit, pntCircle);

            /*
             * // Random rand = new Random(); //Affichons 100 segments de toutes
             * les couleurs for (int i=0; i < 100; i++) { // Affecter une
             * couleur de manière aléatoire paint.setARGB(255,
             * rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256)); //
             * Définir l'épaisseur du segment paint.setStrokeWidth
             * (rand.nextInt(10)); // Puis dessiner nos points dans le cavenas
             * canvas.drawLine(rand.nextInt(iWidth), rand.nextInt(iHeight),
             * rand.nextInt(iWidth), rand.nextInt(iHeight), paint); }
             */
            pnt.setARGB(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256),
                rnd.nextInt(256));
            // Définir l'épaisseur du segment
            pnt.setStrokeWidth(2);

            // Puis dessiner nos points dans le cavenas
            // okcanvas.drawLine((float)((float)Math.cos(0)*rayonDuCerclePetit)+canvas.getWidth()/2,
            // canvas.getHeight()/2,canvas.getWidth()/2+rayonDuCercle,
            // canvas.getHeight()/2, paint);
            // okcanvas.drawLine((float)((float)Math.cos(Math.PI/2)*rayonDuCerclePetit)+canvas.getWidth()/2,
            // ((float)Math.sin(Math.PI/2)*rayonDuCerclePetit)+canvas.getHeight()/2,canvas.getWidth()/2+rayonDuCercle*(float)Math.cos(Math.PI/2),
            // rayonDuCercle*(float)Math.sin(Math.PI/2)+canvas.getHeight()/2,
            // paint);
            // okkk
            // canvas.drawLine((float)((float)Math.cos(Math.PI/4)*rayonDuCerclePetit)+canvas.getWidth()/2,
            // ((float)Math.sin(Math.PI/4)*rayonDuCerclePetit)+canvas.getHeight()/2,canvas.getWidth()/2+rayonDuCercle*(float)Math.cos(Math.PI/4),
            // rayonDuCercle*(float)Math.sin(Math.PI/4)+canvas.getHeight()/2,
            // paint);

            // initPaint(paint,);
        }

        private final void drawRays
        (
            final Canvas cnv, final float rayonDuCercle,
            final float rayonDuCerclePetit
            )
        {
            // pourquoi j'utilise 2 boucles ? Parce que pour limiter l'espace
            // memoire j'utilise le même canva et la seul difference entre ces
            // deux element est la couleur.
            // cette boucle affiche des rayons
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                setRayon(cnv, (Math.PI * .25) * i, pnt, rayonDuCercle,
                    rayonDuCerclePetit);
            }
        }

        private final void drawStars
        (final Canvas cnv, final int width, final int height)
        {
            // j'ai l'impression detre dans les etoiles avec ces petits points
            // Affichons 10000 points de toutes les couleurs
            final int stars = (int) ((width * height) *.01);
            for (int i = stars; i > 0; --i)
            {
                // Affecter une couleur de manière aléatoire
                pnt.setARGB(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256),
                    rnd.nextInt(256));
                // Puis dessiner nos points dans le canevas
                cnv.drawPoint(rnd.nextInt(width), rnd.nextInt(height), pnt);
            }
        }

        /*
         * info pour unen raison que j'ai pas chercher a comprendre l'angle
         * positif s'affiche comme si c'été un ange negatif . Donc je bidouille
         * en multipliant l'angle par -1
         */
        void setRayon
        (
            final Canvas canvas, double angleRad, final Paint paint,
            final float rayonDuCercle, final float rayonDuCerclePetit
            )
        {
            // angleRad=angleRad*-1;
            angleRad = (Math.toRadians(90) + angleRad) * -1;
            canvas.drawLine
            (
                ((float) Math.cos(angleRad) * rayonDuCerclePetit) +
                (float) (canvas.getWidth() * .5),
                ((float) Math.sin(angleRad) * rayonDuCerclePetit) +
                (float) (canvas.getHeight() * .5),
                (float) (canvas.getWidth() * .5) + (rayonDuCercle *
                    (float) Math.cos(angleRad)),
                    (rayonDuCercle * (float) Math.sin(angleRad)) +
                    (float) (canvas.getHeight() * .5), paint
                );
        }
    }
}
```

Please, note how does ContentView differ from your RenderView (not that much, indeed).
It has the same functionality, but I could put it in the **BACKGROUND**, showing the TextViews in front.
 
... why did **I change divisions to multiplication by the inverse**? because it's **FASTER**. On **every** CPU on this world.
The number of stars is 1/100th of the screen area, so it **depends on screen resolution**.
And you'll notice an "**inverse for**" cycle, which is also faster than the normal increasing one.
Now it's just a matter of realigning the TextViews paddings.
And, of course, you have to make the game's logic and draw the sectors in a different color, when touched.
Now it's easy to fire an onClick event on the TextViews...
You should be pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

why you need to draw a circle? in place of that use an image of circle as a background for button and write whatever text you want to write on that. it will be on the center of circle without any worry.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be a simpler solution for most purposes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_circle_white">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    tools:text="7777"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/darkBlue"
     />

</RelativeLayout>
```

using the circle layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >
    <solid android:color="@color/pureBlack" />
</shape>
```