# Design Circular Layout Button or TextView

Tags: android, design-patterns

Can any one help me to understand the below design. Its something like a bunch of (9 including the center one) textviews with onclick feature. Text should be change dynamically which is pretty easy. But the main problem is the design i.e how to put all textviews in this flower pattern, so it will look like the below pic. I have tried a little, seems like I have to understand it before start design.  Can any one help me here.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have look on this links may be it help you ...........

duplicate of :-[Buttons in a circle formation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355206/buttons-in-a-circle-formation)

**OR**

dublicate of :-[Android Layout views rotated and spaced around a circle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14173012/android-layout-views-rotated-and-spaced-around-a-circle)

**OR**

use this libarary:-https://github.com/sababado/CircularView

Last one is too easy............

enjoy coding..............